# Headlines with icon images

Tags: css

I'm working on a design where I'd like to place an Icon to the left of a h2 tag. http://www.toastcafebar.com/stats.html I know that I could add the icon as an image and float the headline text around it but different browsers will render the positioning differently causing the icon to be slightly out of line. I also intend to have a number of structured headlines with icons so in an effort to keep CSS short and lean I'm wondering if there is any alternative method.

For web standards I know it's best to add the image in CSS rather than in the html but for learning purposes I'm curious to know if you can add an image inline within the html markup.....

What would be the standards compliant yet leanest way to achieve this?

Comment: Add screen shot image instead of posting links.

Comment: @HarryJoy Unfortunately I can't attach images until I've reached 10 posts :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the CSS I've used for this purpose:

```
h2
{
    background: url('image.png') no-repeat;
    padding-left: 45px; /* width of image */
}
```

Comment: Nice one! What would happen if instead of a h1 I had a number of h2 headlines with different icons? Would I need to create separate classes?

Comment: This is definitely best practice, unless the image will need alt text for screen readers or something.  If that's the case you could always do something like the following:
    `<h2 class="iconh2"><img src="whatever.png" alt="Whatever" />Text</h2>`
and for css:
    `.iconh2 { position:relative; padding-left:45px; }`
    `.iconh2 img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }`

Don't forget to adjust your styles for position accordingly

Comment: @Jedda Separate classes is what I would use if I needed different images.

Comment: While you're at it, put all those icons in a sprite file... just for good measure.